# Is there a large performance difference between find and find2perl

Tags: ssh, command-line, command

Is there a performance difference between find and find2perl? I work for a hosting company and I was told that our admins prefer us to use find2perl over find. Supposedly this is because find is heavier on resource usage than find2perl? Does anyone know if this is true and if so, could you please explain why?

Comment: I would guess that's incorrect. But the best way to answer that would be to benchmark it on your systems.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know that time benchmarking can be done with the time command but do you have any recommendations for benchmarking CPU / memory usage as well?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question "Is there a performance difference between find and find2perl?"
yes :-)

The last time I remember testing this ( when find2perl was faster ) as back on Sun Microsystems sparc and NFS.  At the time the speed improvements when using find2perl was considerable.

Today, I ran some tests on cygwin and wsl between find vs. find2perl, and found that find2perl was about 4 times slower in both cases.

Answer (score -2):

The development and admin teams of the company you refer to have an affinity to perl which stems back to the inception of the original system architecture they use. This has led to a kind of company culture that favors perl. Notice that every time this question is asked in a forum, the question starts with "I work for a hosting company, and everyone here says..." Just google "find vs. find2perl" and look through the results. You'll see the same preface every time this is asked. You won't find any real evidence that the rumor is true because there is none. Everyone heard it from someone else, who heard it from someone else, who heard it from someone who just favors perl.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to write an answer. However, I am aware of the favoritism and the underlying scenario which conceived it. I'm more so seeking a technical breakdown of the two through performance benchmarking on identical systems and other reliable means of testing. It's something I could attempt myself but with that said, I'm certain there are users on this forum which have more insight and knowledge about unix derived systems and optimal means of performing tests which could lead to a conclusion.